# Carry-save multiplier algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I am having a hard time deciphering how carry-save multiplication is done (in binary, specifically). Here is a block diagram of the carry-save multiplier against the usual multiplier.

[image: binary array multiplier vs carry-save multiplier]

Since the inputs to the adders in the carry-save multiplier are quite vague, I've searched more on carry-save multipliers. Out of the few I've gotten, I think these are helpful but I don't understand the *i* and *j* part.

[image]

[image]

---

**Here's what I'm currently working on:**

Say that we have a 4-bit multiplicand *A B C D* and 4-bit multiplier *W X Y Z*.

```
  A B C D
* W X Y Z
----------
```

Shown below is the logic I'm working on for the carry-save multiplier. (It is still producing an erroneous product.) Disregarding the language I've used in coding, I think the lines are pretty straightforward. The ones at the leftmost are just identifiers. The outputs are either sum (S<sub>n</sub>) or carry (C<sub>n</sub>). The ones in the inputs, aside from the previous sum and carry values, are (partial) products. For example, PZD means the product of Z and D (refer to the setting above).

```
       *OUTS      *INS          *SUBCKT
XHA1   S1  C1     PZD 0         HALFADDER
XHA2   S2  C2     PZC PYD       HALFADDER
XHA3   S3  C3     PZB PYC       HALFADDER
XHA4   S4  C4     PZA PYB       HALFADDER

XFA1   S5  C5     S2 PXD C1     FULLADDER
XFA2   S6  C6     S3 PXC C2     FULLADDER
XFA3   S7  C7     S4 PXB C3     FULLADDER
XHA5   S8  C8     C4 PXA        HALFADDER

XFA4   S9  C9     S6 PWD C5     FULLADDER
XFA5   S10 C10    S7 PWC C6     FULLADDER
XFA6   S11 C11    S8 PWB C7     FULLADDER
XHA6   S12 C12    C8 PWA        HALFADDER

XHA7   S13 C13    S10 C9        HALFADDER
XFA7   S14 C14    S11 C10 C13   FULLADDER
XFA8   S15 C15    S12 C11 C14   FULLADDER
XHA8   S16 C16    C11 C12       HALFADDER
```

The final output are `S16 S15 S14 S13 S9 S5 S1`, with `S16` as the most significant bit. 
Can you help me understand how carry-save multiplier works?

Comment: To avoid any confusion, ignore all literature on Radix-4/Booth encoding. Then the first stage runs "ANDs" between every two bits to produce partial products. Then all these products are added in N Wallace trees that are made of CSAs (carry save adders; another name is a "3:2 compressor"). All the sums from the Wallace forest must be treated as one 2*N-bit number, and all the carries as another 2*N-bit number, and the both numbers are simply added together (in a fast lookahead carry propagate adder; I advice to use a hierarchy of 4-bit adders) to form the final 2*N-bit result (plus carry).